# Make a fixed div stop at a specific time before reaching the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well this must be like the millionth time someone asked for help about this, but I can't find a solution no matter what I try. I am having a div with 2 images on my website that are working like clickable ads at the right column of the products list. This div is fixed but I want it, when you scroll down, to stop at like 300px before the bottom of the page. I know that I need javascript for this and, even though I know a little HTML, I am not good with it and I cant seem to figure out what I need to do to make it work, no matter how many times I look for a solution.
I leave the code below with the div I am using.

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <a title="Link Here">
      <div id="paper">
        <img src="Image Here"/>
      </div>
    </a>
    <br />
    <a href="Link Here">
      <div id="product">
        <img src="Image Here"/>
        <br />
        <div id="description">
          ...Text Here....
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS,

```
  #main{
        width: 180px;
        height: auto;
        position: fixed;  
        padding-bottom: 300px;
    }
  #product{
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: rgba(235,235,235,0.8);
        width: 180px;
        height: 270px;
    }
  #product img{
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;   
        }
    #product:hover{
        border-color: red;
    }
    #paper{
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: rgba(235,235,235,0.8);
        width: 180px;
        height: auto;
    }
    #paper img{
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;   
        }
    #paper:hover{
         border-color: red;
    }
     #description{
        text-align: center;
        width: 95%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 520px;
        background-color: rgba(215,81,83,0.5);
        color: white;
        left: 4.5px;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question would have a much better change of getting an answer if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To extend on @GhassenLouhaichi, your example is not appropriate to reproduce your problem: for a start, your HTML is invalid (closed tags that are never opened) and it is not scrollable. It shouldn't be our task to fix the code to be able to see your problem

Comment: @PeterCsala please do not edit the OP's syntax errors, they should be explained in an comment or answer. It can also make harder for potential answerers to fix the problem

Comment: @Kaddath Sorry, I suggested an update where I reverted back the syntax correction.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I recreated it here https://jsfiddle.net/pm3n201s/ sorry if it isn't right my post, I am new and I don't know well what is needed to get the help I wanted...I wish the example is easier to figure it out...I want the red divs I created to stop before they reach the blue div(stop before they reach the last 100px at the bottom of the page)

Comment: @JohnKara I am confused when you say that the red divs should ***stop***, because they are the only divs that never move, they are fixed, so they are always stopped. Do you maybe mean the blue div should stop when it reaches the bottom of the red divs?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yes that's what I meant...sorry if I'm confusing you

Comment: @JohnKara I don't have the full solution in mind, but it sounds like the idea is to calculate the offset of the bottom of the red div from the top of screen and use the [CSS sticky position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on the blue div to fix it at the bottom of the red div when it scrolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without Javascript. The easiest solution here is to use `position: sticky;`. It is relatively new, so it is is not supported by oldest browsers ([see here for compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility)).

An element with sticky positionning will keep the defined position according to scroll position (Here `top: 0;`) but will stay in the limits of its container when it scrolls out of the window:

```css
#body{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#maindiv{
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
#div-1{
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.8);
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
}
#div-2{
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.8);
  width: 180px;
  height: 270px;
}
#bottom{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="maindiv">
      <div id="div-1"> 
      </div>
      <div id="div-2">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk a lot @Kaddath! It work perfectly fine for my work...I only see that the sticky element is not compatible with internet explorer but if it's working on chrome opera and mozilla it's fine by me

Comment: @JohnKara Yep but it only means old versions of Windows browser, as it was renamed you can see it is supported by Edge